# Slow resolve time

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, resolve

When it comes to servers I defiantly struggle I have recently set up a rack space cloud. I have two domains pointing to it: `http://www.nintendowiis.com` and the actual domain I will be using for it `http://www.quinc.co.uk`.

For some reason quinc.o.uk takes around 15 seconds to resolve, where as nintendowiis.com takes no time what so ever.

I'm running ubuntu 10.10 maveric.

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: What is doing the resolving? Are you using the rackspace nameservers?

Comment: Please give details on how you are testing the resolve.  Both names resolve quickly for me using Google name-servers or AT&T name-servers.

Comment: Is this an ad for those two sites?

Comment: As an aside, be prepared to lose that first domain as part of a UDRP complaint.  That is a pretty blatant trademark violation.

Comment: @blankabout I am using the rackspace nameservers

I only set the first site to be apart of the rackspace account since I'd never done it before and wernt going to blindly stop pointing my domain to a new server without knowing I could get it working or not, its not an advert either @embobo.
Im not server savy so Im seeking advice from experts who clearly know/have a far better understanding then myself, and Iv owned the first domain for years, it was used just for TEST purposes, I was just going by the basis that it seems to take while to load, but there may be other iimplications there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did a dig, this is what I got. How are you measuring the DNS resolution time. The time taken to connect to http://www.quinc.co.uk is not the correct way of measuring DNS response time.

```
$ dig www.quinc.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> www.quinc.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57080
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.quinc.co.uk.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.quinc.co.uk.    300 IN  CNAME   quinc.co.uk.
quinc.co.uk.        300 IN  A   46.38.174.93

;; Query time: 653 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 16 23:45:32 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

Even with a +trace flag, dig it takes 306ms